# How to calculate the data for yaxis manually?

Tags: d3.js

I'm using d3.js with Reactjs and trying to let Reactjs handle all the dom manipulation and let d3.js just do the math for the graph(s). This is fairly straightforward, except that I'm having difficulty with the yAxis. Usually (when not using Reactjs) I create the yAxis like this

```
var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(y)
      .orient("left")

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
    .attr("y", 6)
    .attr("dy", ".71em")
     .style("text-anchor", "end")
```

and it adds 10 `g` of `tick` class with a text and line element inside each, magically calculating the transform and the text value (below represented by ???)

```
   <g class="tick" transform="**?**">
       <text dy=".32em" x="-9" y="0" style="text-anchor:end">**?**</text>
       <line x2="-6" y2="0"></line>
   </g>
```

so if I were to create the data for each tick manually, I need to calculate the transform and also the text.  yAxis is normally called with `call`

```
`.call(yAxis)`
```

but is there another way that I can call it so that I can generate the data for transform and the text value for each tick?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is no -- the axis component isn't designed to return computed values, it's designed to draw the axis.

The slightly longer answer is that you can use the `.ticks()` function of the scale to generate the tick values and then compute the positions accordingly (using the same scale). You don't need the axis component at all. The code would look something like this.

```
var scale = d3.scale.linear().domain(...).range(...),
    ticks = scale.ticks();

d3.selectAll("g.tick").data(ticks).enter()
  .append("g")
  // add tick lines and text
```

On a general note, you're usually better off using D3 for this rather than something else like Reactjs. In particular you're going to be reimplementing at least part of the functionality of the axis component to make this work properly.

Comment: thank you, I didn't know that I could generate the tick values like that. That helps, but it's only one half of what I need. Can you tell me how to generate the transform value, which I believe is used to position the tick on the y-axis? You can see in my OP the data each tick needs 1) the tick value (which you've given me) but also the transform value

Comment: i.e. when I ask how to cacluate the transform value, I mean the 10 corresponding transform values (since scale.ticks(); generates 10 tick values). Is there a function that I can call to do that?

Comment: You simply pass the generated tick values to the scale.